# How to read memory mapped file which is in particular format?

Tags: java, arrays, nio, memory-mapped-files, bytebuffer

I am working with Memory Mapped file in Java. I have a particular user id data stored in Avro Binary encoded format inside memory mapped file.

The memory mapped file consists of two main parts:
- a header which serves as a an index into the full files contents, specifically answering questions the file as well as giving the offset into the file for each user's data.
- a body followed by the data for each user in the file at the given offset.

**Header**

```
version                     4 bytes
last_modified_date          8 bytes
users                       4 bytes
shards                      4 bytes
the shards                  N * 4 bytes
num_hash_index              4 bytes
num_chain_slots             4 bytes
user offset/size index      num_hash_index * num_chain_slots * (8 bytes + 8 bytes + 4 bytes)
```

And now the header is followed by the body which is described as shown below.

**Body**

```
number of records                   2 bytes         how many records does this user have?
a repeated sequence of records      variable size   as described below
```

All the records follow this specification:

```
attribute key                       X bytes     a string of the users key.
key delimiter                       1 bytes     '\0'
client id                           2 bytes     some client id
last modified time (in ms)          8 bytes     This is the last modified time for this attribute in ms.
length of the avro binary data      2 bytes     actual length of avro binary data
the binary avro data or text        Y bytes     Length given by the previous field.
```

Now I have lot of files already generated with the above format. I need to read this file from Java program. What is the best way to do this in Java? This is the first time I am working with Memory Mapped file so trying to understand how should I proceed on this?

```
FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(new File("c:/tmp/file.txt"), "rw").getChannel();
```

Now I am not sure what I should do? Any example will help me to understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. The key are the methods in DataInputStream which read and convert bytes. I suppose the endianness is suitable.

```
 ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate( 9999 ); // capacity
 int nRead = fc.read( buf );
 InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( buf.array() );
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream( is );
 int version = dis.readInt(); //                   4 bytes
 long timestamp = dis.readLong();  //                 8 bytes
 int numUsers = dis.readInt(); //                   4 bytes
```

And so on.

**More details on the Body**

There's no need to store the key delimiter ('\0') and the length of the avro data, which is expressed by the byte array's length. I'm using an int to store the short integers, just to be on the safe side (no unsigned short in Java),

```
public class UserAttribute {
  private final String attributeKey;
  private final int schemaId;               // unsigned short
  private final long lastModifiedDate;
  private final byte[] avroBinaryData;      // preceded by length: unsigned short
  // constructor and getters here

}

int numberOfAttributes = dis.readShort();
List<UserAttribute> ual = new ArrayList<>( numberOfAttributes );
for( int iAttr = 0; iAttr < numberOfAttributes; ++iAttr ){
    // read values for one attribute, create UserAttribute  object
    UserAttribute ua = new UserAttribute();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(;;){
        int ub = dis.readUnsignedByte(); // can this be in ISO-8859-1 > 0x80?
        if( ub == 0 ) break;
        sb.append( (char)ub );
    }
    ua.setAttributeKey( sb.toString() );
    ua.setSchemaId( dis.readUnsignedShort() );
    ua.setLastModifiedDate( dis.readLong() );
    int loabd = dis.readUnsignedShort();
    byte[] abd = new byte[loabd];
    for( int ib = 0; ib < loabd; ++ib ){
        abd[ib] = dis.readByte();
    }
    ua.setAvroBinaryData();
    ual.add( ua );
}
```

Also, I think reading the shards should be

```
int numShards = dis.readInt(); // 4 bytes 1..101
int[] shards = new int[numShards];
for( il = 0; il < numShards; ++il ){
    shards[il] = dis.readInt(); //  N * 4 bytes     Where N is the number of shards
}
```

**Even Later** Memory mapping

```
int read = ...;
FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
ByteBuffer buffer = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, read );
buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
```

This results in a ByteBuffer of the given length containing the file data. If the file is larger than 0x7fffffff, it must be mapped in chunks, which is possible using the same FileChannel method, i.e., map.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got the understanding now what I need to do but I am confuse what I need to do on the body part? Since `a repeated sequence of attributes` will not just be one, they will be multiple so how long I will keep on iterating. In general, I need to keep on iterating as long as data is there for a particular user id.

Comment: You can read the "number of attributes" and then repeat. For the zero-delimited string, you'll have to get byte by byte. Probably you should use readUnsignedByte() and then convert to a string, but watch out for the encoding of that string. As for the "avro data or text", you'll have to know what it is, otherwise it's just "bytes".

Comment: Yeah for avro encoding, I know how to decode that so I will easily be able to decode that. Do you want me to read everything as `readUnsignedByte` or only certain fields for UserAttribute?

Comment: Signed byte values may not be useful when you have to combine bytes into a wider binary integer or some string. You can combine four unsigned bytes (int in the range 0:255) to anything you need. If the binary data contains an unsigned 2 or 4 byte integer, you should use a Java int or long. - Other methods may be preferable in certain places, e.g., readUnsignedShort.

Comment: Thanks got the idea. I have updated the question with the code for `UserAttribute` class and the actual body retrieval code as I had some confusion in that. See if you can help me with that as  well. if anything is wrong in my code then can you please provide an example on the body retrieval part as well?

Comment: Updated my answer which should about cover it all. I haven't even tried to compile it, sorry if there are typos.

Comment: Yup I got most of the stuff working now. I am able to extract all the header fields now but I am not able to extract any body stuff, not sure why. If you are around, then we can chat on this. It looks like there is some offset for the user's location.

Comment: I've seen "num hash slots" and "num chain entries" which indicates that there is some hash table following the header. You may have to read the C++ program to see how the data is stored unless you have some doc. - I'll be around for the next 14 hrs, although with breaks.